# How do you prove the group (Zn\{0}, *) has an inverse element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I understand that I want first suppose there is an $a$ and find a general $a^{-1}$. So I suppose that $[a]_n * [a^{-1}]_n = e = 1$.

I'm struggling to find $a^{-1}$.

I think I need to  I want to say that $a^{-1}$ is $1/[a]_n$, but then the inverse will not be an integer, which is absurd. 
Or maybe I try to find the order of a where it will become $e$?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not true in general. Consider $(\Bbb Z_4,\cdot)$. Furthermore, the notation $\frac{1}{x}$ really only makes sense for real numbers. It does not make sense for a general group.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: $\frac{1}{x}$ makes sense for a general abelian group whose operation is written multiplicatively, as an alternate notation for $x^{-1}$.

Comment: @ashtonn: A good writing tip is that you should define notation when you introduce it. this is especially if you aren't going to typeset your post so it looks like how things are usually written.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks! I'm pretty new to proof-based math, but I will work towards defining notation and possibly learn how to typeset!

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof that an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ which is relatively prime to $n$ has an inverse is the following:  Since $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax + ny = 1$.  Now reducing mod $n$ gives that $ax=1$, so the inverse of $a$ is $x$.  To find $x$ (and $y$), use the Euclidean Algorithm.